# Question about principal part and residue.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this theorem from Stein and Shakarchi:
[image: page1]

Here is a description of the principal part:
[image: page2]
I don't understand the statement, that all other terms in the principal part, with order strictly greater than one have primitives in a deleted neighborhood of $z_0$. Consequently I am not seeing how we arrive at the formula for residue.

I am also trying to understand residue intuitively. What can be an intuitive definition?

Answer (score 1):

For $n\ge 2$, the function
$$\frac{a_{-n}}{(z-z_0)^n}$$
has the primitive
$$-\frac{a_{-n}}{(n-1)(z-z_0)^{n-1}}$$
defined in a neighbourhood of $z_0$. But
$$\frac{a_{-1}}{(z-z_0)^1}$$
has no such primitive, unless $a_{-1}$ (the residue) is zero.

Comment: So  @AnginaSeng are you saying  $\int_C \frac{1}{z-z_{0}}dz$ not exist? why? The second part of my question is how we arrived at the $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C P(z) dz = a_{-1}$ and the intuition behind residue.

Comment: In fact $\int_C \frac{1}{z} dz$ in a deleted neighborhood of the origin is $2\pi i$

Comment: This is an inadequate answer @AnginaSeng